# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON ! Api request failing in express js

Tags: json, node.js, express

Im using express JS for to write API's and im fairly new to this ! ive been able to write my code for login, logout  and register etc. But when trying to create an API for creating and order im getting

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>     at Object.stringify (native)
>     at stringify (/Users/vaishakdinesh/Desktop/Web Design/webDesignProject/SousChef/SousChefWeb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1064:12)
>     at ServerResponse.json (/Users/vaishakdinesh/Desktop/Web Design/webDesignProject/SousChef/SousChefWeb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:243:14)
>     at ServerResponse.send (/Users/vaishakdinesh/Desktop/Web Design/webDesignProject/SousChef/SousChefWeb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:152:21)
>     at /Users/vaishakdinesh/Desktop/Web Design/webDesignProject/SousChef/SousChefWeb/API/authenticate.js:20:13
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/vaishakdinesh/Desktop/Web

This is my code for passport in my expressjs file.

```
passport.use('order', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req,done) {
        console.log("creating a new order");
        var newOrder = new Order();
        var obj = req.body.order;
        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            newOrder.order[i].name = obj[i].name;
            newOrder.order[i].subtotal = obj[i].subtotal;
            newOrder.order[i].serving = obj[i].serving;
            newOrder.order[i].price = obj[i].price;
            newOrder.order[i].people = obj[i].people;
        }
        newOrder.charge.total = obj.charge.total;
        newOrder.charge.shipping = obj.charge.shipping;
        newOrder.user = obj.user;

        newOrder.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("saving error");
                return done("error in ordering",err);
            }
            console.log("order saved !");
            return(null,newOrder);
        });
    })
);
```

and the JSON object im sending looks like:

```
     {
  "order":[
    {
      "name":"Butter chicken",
      "subtotal":"10",
      "serving":1,
      "people":1,
      "price":"10.00",
      "shortname":"Butter_Chicken"
    },
    {
      "name":"Butter chicken",
      "subtotal":"10",
      "serving":1,
      "people":1,
      "price":"10.00",
      "shortname":"Butter_Chicken"
    }
  ],
  "charge":[
    {
      "total":20,
      "shipping":0
    }
  ],
  "user":"v@gmail.com"
}
```

Does anyone know why this error is occurring ? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
router.get('/success', function(req, res){
    req.session.cookie.lastLogin = new Date().getTime();
    req.session.name = req.user.name;
    req.session.username = req.user.email;
    req.session.password = req.user.password;
    res.send({status: 200,state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
});

router.get('/mail/success', function(req, res){
    res.send({status: 200,state: 'failure', message:req ? req : null});
});
```

and

```
router.post('/order', passport.authenticate('order', { 
    successRedirect: '/auth/success', 
    failureRedirect: '/auth/failure' 
}));
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Can you show us the code where the error is happening (probably `res.send` in "authenticate.js")?

Comment: ... I meant for you to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41071523/edit). Code snippets are not meant for comments.